# Separation of concerns: Just a computer science term?

Tags: terminology

I studied computer science, that's why the term "Separation of concerns" is common for me.

I read the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Now I am unsure. Up to now I thought this term gets used outside computer science, too.

I thought it is a general principle to answer the question "who is responsible for what?".

Can you use the term "Separation of concerns" outside computer science to answer the question "who is responsible for what?"?

Comment: I can think of no reason why the three words used together would be ungrammatical. However, answering *Who is responsible for what?* with *separation of concerns* doesn't make any sense. Do you mean to actually use that phrase in a longer answer to the question? If so, can you provide the complete answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to borrow a term from computer science (often done) into a business environment. Your familiarity with it, and it's a great idea, has got your thinking that everyone uses it. In a few years I'm sure it will be so but for now I agree with the comment that it is not yet sensible.